# strongloop, how to define a response class for a custom endpoint

Tags: javascript, swagger, strongloop

According to the documentation you can create custom response classes;
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-Argumentdescriptions

The remote method description I use is:

common/models/products-sku.js

`ProductsSku.remoteMethod(
    'getSomeData',
    {
      http: {path: '/getSomeData', verb: 'get'},
      accepts: {arg: 'filter', type: 'object', http: { source: 'query'} },
      returns: {
        arg: 'id',
        description: 'Custom endpoint',
        type: 'CustomProductType',
        root: true
      }
    }
  );`

In the same file I have a definition for the CustomProductType;

`var CustomProductType: {
  id: Number,
  name: String,
  ...
};`

Now if I open the explorer the response class is defined as CustomProductType but there is no model definition in the /explorer/resources/ProductsSku swagger definition (this is still swagger 1.2)

As this is not an actual model, how do i register/define the model, such that it is send with the api definition.

==
What I have tried:

common/models/products-sku.js:

`var DataSource = require('loopback-datasource-juggler').DataSource;
var ds = new DataSource('memory');
ds.define('CustomProductType', CustomProductType);`

The memory datasource is because it is not an actual Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is not in the documentation, here is what I did.

Add the name of the response class you like to the remoteMethod definition
as I did above with the `type: 'CustomProductType'`

Go to the server/model-config.json file and add the type there

`"CustomProductType": {
  "dataSource": false,
  "public": true
}`

now add your model definition to the `common/models/custom_product_type.json`